# What is the right way to invoke a button's click event?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, button, compact-framework, windows-ce

Here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hkkb40tf(v=VS.90).aspx, it says that, to call a button's click event from another button, you can/should do it this way:

```
button1.PerformClick();
```

However, in my situation (VS 2003. NET 1.1), this doesn't compile (admittedly, the link above specifies VS 2008, but it does not have a link to the pertinent info for prior versions, as msdn often does).

This compiles:

```
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
{
    if (this.recordChanged)
    {
        //btnSave.Click();
        btnSave_Click(sender, args);
    }
    . . .
```

...but I don't know if it's THE way to do it.

Comment: What is the compile error?

Comment: WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET?

Comment: Sorry; I changed the Tags now (Windows CE)/WinForms, so to speak. Compile error is 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' does not contain a definition for 'PerformClick'

Comment: This link specifies .NET 1.1 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Since PerformClick() is shown there for .NET 1.1, it must be the CE element that is preventing it.

Comment: Button.PerformClick() does NOT exists in the CompactFramework. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button_methods(v=vs.90).aspx
Notice there is no PDA-Icon next to the Method for CF and that CF is not listed under the documentation for the method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the business logic that you want to execute in a separate method (e.g. DoSave()), and then your event handlers can both just call that internal method rather than calling each other directly.

"Faking" events by calling the event handler methods directly is ugly and can lead to bugs (any programmer modifying the event handler in future may be unaware that it could be called under different conditions than expected/documented, which could cause the print option to behave strangely or even crash when it tries to do a save operation)

Also there is a good chance that you may want to cause a save operation from somewhere else in future - so it's always a very good idea to keep the business logic separate from the use interface that activates it.

Comment: +1, this cannot be emphasized enough! Another reason to do the semantically correct thing is to avoid WTFs during future maintenance and changes.

Comment: Good point; I normally do that when coding something new, but in maintaining an existing app and taking the instructions for adding this functionality a little too literally, I veered from my normal habit.

Comment: This is the correct solution, do not rely on your GUI handlers to execute your business logic. Find a way to invoke the business logic directly.

Answer (score 0):

I would do `btnSave.Click(sender, args);`. Here's the page on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=VS.71).aspx

Comment: You cannot do this when the event is declared as an `event`, since `event` limits all but `+=` and `-=` to a private scope.